# Joomla - OnMouseover show data from controller in tooltip using Qtip script

Tags: ajax, joomla, tooltip, qtip

I need help to show the data (from controller) in tooltip (using qTip script) on MouseOVer event.

1. User mouserover on link (Multiple links like in foreach)
2. id send to a js function like function getData(id){}
3. Call the PHP function from the controller & using the variable return the data to tooltip.
4. Show return data into tooltip.

**HTML & PHP:**

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    <a href="#" onmouseover="getData(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)" >Name</a>
}
```

**JS function :**

```
function getData(id)
{
    var url='index.php?option=com_test&controller=test&task=getDetails&format=raw';
    var data = 'item_id=' + id ;
    var request = new Request({
    url: url,
    method:'post',
    data: data,
    async: true,
    onSuccess: function(responseText)
{ 
    // How i show the "responseText" data here in tooltip using qTip
}
}).send();      
}
```

**Controller function:**

```
function getDetails()
{
   echo $return = JRequest::getVar('item_id');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to preload the tip in a content item view override (add it to the title= attribute), and adding the call to qTip (one per page) would do the trick.

Also, ajax would make the tooltip not very quick.

Just make sure you properly escape " or ' characters in the title attribute or you will break your markup.

edit: added code. i'm writing this here so there may be typos, but it should give you the idea:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // let's assume $tip contains the right tip for each row:
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $tip; ?>" class="tipme">Name</a>
}
```

This first part will show the default browser tooltip.

Now you have to inject the qTip script:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery("a.tipme").qTip();
');
```

Now how to put the value in $tip?  I see you have a com_test component, you don't need to go through the controller, but can instantiate directly the model that will provide the tooltip; if it's called "tip":

```
$tipmodel=JModel::getInstance('tip', 'ComtestModel'); // get the model (once!)

$tip = $tipmodel->getTip($row->id);
```

All the variable, model, controller names in this story are fictional.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo, 
Sorry but can you explain it with an example? Also i modified the HTML & PHP code. please check.